# Get All Subscription Statuses Returns Only Expired Transaction

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

While I was testing my application, I first subscribed to yearly subscription plan. Later, I have switched to monthly plan. They are both in the same subscription group. In Swift, Transaction.currentEntitlements returns both transactions. (monthly and yearly)

I also have a server setup where I use the App Store Server API. I am trying to get the same subscription information with the [Get All Subscription Statuses](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/get_all_subscription_statuses) endpoint. However, this endpoint only returns the latest subscribed plan which is monthly. I want to use this endpoint to set the expiration date on my backend. The problem is although user has a yearly plan that can be seen in the Transaction.currentEntitlements, this endpoint does not include that so the expiration date is set from the monthly plan where as it should be the yearly expiration date. Moreover, when the monthly plan is expired, Transaction.currentEntitlements only shows the yearly plan as expected. However, the endpoint still shows the expired monthly plan.

So, as far as I understand, this endpoint is not showing the Transaction.currentEntitlements but rather the latest active subscription plan. Should I use Get Transaction History endpoint instead to set my expiration date to the latest date or am I missing something over here?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this issue from happening, you need to arrange the subscription order from App Store Connect.

[image]

I have moved the yearly subscription above the monthly subscription. After doing that, if a user subscribes to a monthly plan while in a yearly plan(higher level service), currentEntitlements and the app store server endpoint shows just the yearly plan. Once the yearly plan expires, the monthly plan will be active at both places. This way I can rely on the expirationDate.